# How to change the track color in a slider in wpf

Tags: wpf

Here is the code, i have to change the color of track when the slider is moved.
Please give me a solution

```
  <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
          <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton >
                                <RepeatButton    Style="{StaticResource    SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"/>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton     Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb"  Style="{StaticResource CustomThumbForSlider}" Background="Black"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in your **SliderRepeatButtonStyle** style. **Background** attribute defines a color for the inside part of the track, **BorderBrush** attribute defines a color for the track border.

```
<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="Red"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="OrangeRed" Height="3"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```